# How to assign a version in gem/bundle in Octopress

Tags: ruby, bundler, octopress, kramdown

As you can see I have two version of kramdown. I want to use kramdown 1.0.2 in my Octopress. How can I assign it?

```
➜  octopress git:(source) ✗ kramdown --version
1.0.2
➜  octopress git:(source) ✗ bundle show kramdown
/Users/teacher/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/kramdown-0.13.
```

When I check bundle list, it outputs,

```
 * kramdown (0.13.8)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'kramdown', '1.0.2'
```

and then

```
bundle
```